# Is there always a purely real representative for a metrized solvable Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Alekseevski proves for Heintze groups (a special class of solvable Lie groups) that any such group admits a (left-invariant) metric which is isometric to a purely real Heintze group (again equipped with some left-invariant metric).

Can the same be said for arbitrary solvable Lie groups? Here by purely real, I mean that the adjoint action has purely real eigenvalues when acting as an automorphism of the Lie algebra.

EDIT: In case it is relevant, I am only interested in those solvable Lie groups which admit nonpositively curved (CAT(0)) metrics.